# Redirecting one clean url to another issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect `example.com/en/**Weight_Loss-p370**` to `example.com/en/**Weight_Loss-c145**`, because the first is a duplicate page of the second.

I have tried many things, but for example when I add this line in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /en/Weight_Loss-p370 http://example.com/en/Weight_Loss-c145
```

I get: `example.com/en/Weight_Loss-c145?sys_lang=en&elem_id=370`

Some parameters appear from nothing.

Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: The parameters are appearing because a `RewriteRule` parsing the first URL is still triggering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to other rules that are changing REQUEST_URI before this rule executed.

You can use this rule as **your very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# specific URLs
RewriteRule ^(en/Weight_Loss)-p370/?$ /$1-c145? [L,NC,R=301]

# remaining URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . http://siteB.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Oh great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please help me with one more thing? I have rewritten some of the urls, now I want to redirect all other urls that are indexed by google to the home page of site B.
With other words: All urls that are not rewritten to what page to redirect, to auto redirect to home page.
Thanks :)

Comment: Try `RewriteRule . /?` as the very least rule. I am on mobile do can't test but you may need to skip js/CSS/image files from this rule.

Comment: Sorry I was offline for 2 days. What is giving 500 error? Can you show your latest .htaccess in question to clarify

Comment: No problem, I am thankful that you are helping. How can I send you the htaccess? When I put RewriteRule . /? as the last rule, the other redirects work but the home page shows 500 error.

Comment: check updated answer and replace `siteB.com` with your actual domain.